# Add class to the row where the checkbox is in

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How can i add a class to the row, where the checkbox i selected, is in the tr?

Now, it selects all the , exept the one i wanted.

Thanks for help!

```
echo '<tr id="sor'.intval($a['kapcsolat_id']).'">
                            <td class="left"><input class="table_row_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="'.intval($a['kapcsolat_id']).'" /></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">'.intval($a['kapcsolat_id']).'</td>
                            <td class="left">'.html($a['kapcsolat_nev']).'</td>
                            <td class="left">'.html($a['kapcsolat_email']).'</td>
                            <td class="left">'.html($a['kapcsolat_tel']).'</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">'.date_substr($a['kapcsolat_date']).'</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; color:'.$color.'">'.$status.'</td>
                            <td class="right">
                                <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$admin_folder.'/beerkezett-uzenet.php?id='.intval($a['kapcsolat_id']).'"><span class="btn btn-sm button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></a>
                                <a id="'.intval($a['kapcsolat_id']).'" href="#" class="deleteLink"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></a>
                            </td>
                         </tr>';



$('.table_row_checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest(":has(tr)").find('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    } 
    else {
        $(this).closest(":has(tr)").find('tr').removeClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).closest("tr").parent().find('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");`

Comment: It does the same, as my code.

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").addClass("checkbox_checked_row");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function(){

    $('.table_row_checkbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    } 
    else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get parent element:

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('checkbox_checked_row');
```

---

In you case:

Fist parent = td

Second parent = tr